# CLI error permission denied when connecting to SQL Server via SAS ODBC

Tags: permissions, sas, odbc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZckL.png)

The user I am using has the highest allowed privilege in the db. We've also tested the script against the DB and we are able to delete but when running it in SAS this happens.

Would appreciate your help, guys!

Comment: Can you just copy and paste the message as text? The photograph is hard to read and harder to paste into a google search.

Comment: Need more details: are you running locally or using a SAS server?  What OS is SAS running on? Are you using NT authentication or user/password?

Comment: I am running it in a wirtual machine, Windows 7 and ODBC DSN is config for NT authentication

Answer (score 0):

This is a DB error.  You are not using the same account to connect with SAS.  Check your ODBC settings

Comment: Hi allan, what do you mean by same account to connect with sas? Im using only one account to access the SQL server

Comment: which SAS product are you using?  can you share the libname statement?

Answer (score 0):

I addressed the issue by selecting

> With SQL server authentication using a login ID ad password entered by
>   the user in ODBC config

. I missed to check that the network login is diff from the server log in that is why I could not access it. :)